# Build error after updating to com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am running into the following error while building my android project:

```
AAPT: <project directory>\app\build\intermediates\stable_resource_ids_file\debug\stableIds.txt: error: failed to open: The data is invalid. (13).
```

it started happening after updating my `build.gradle` file in the project's `app` directory from `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        ...

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For now, I am avoiding the issue by downgrading from `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3` in the `build.gradle` file in the project's `app` directory:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"     // <--- downgrade to 4.1.3 to avoid build error!!
        ...

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and i fixed that with :

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn install
```